# CAPL - Get signal value description from dbc

Tags: capl, canoe

I'm searching a solution in CAPL that allows me to get the value description of a signal described in the dbc.

For example, I have the following signal that has the indicated value:

```
msgStatusCCAN1.PowerMode = 1
```

- msgStatusCCAN1 is the message
- PowerMode is the signal
- 1 is the value that corresponds in the DBC to ON

So, is there a method that doing for example `getDescription(message,signal,value)` will give me the description of that value that it is ON?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the signal PowerMode has associated Value Table then your CAPL code can refer to value ON as follows:

```
msgStatusCCAN1.PowerMode = msgStatusCCAN1.PowerMode::ON
```